# How is the angular momentum conserved in this case?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotation

So imagine we have a mass attached to a string and spin it. If angular momentum is conserved then why does the object not have a tendency to move in a curved path if the mass is suddenly let go off. Linear momentum appears to be conserved in this case at an instantaneous point where the mass $M$ would have velocity $v$ at any given point and hence a linear momentum of $Mv$ which presumably dies out due to gravity and drag. Where is the angular momentum gone?

Comment: Why do you think the angular momentum has disappeared? Calculate it and see if it really has disappeared

Comment: This video explains your question really well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWSu6U0Ujs8

Answer (score 0):

The angular momentum goes nowhere (assuming no external torques are applied while leaving the string). The angular momentum of a point mass (I am assuming the ball to be a point mass, but angular momentum is conserved even when you assume the ball to be a rigid body) can be expressed as

$$\mathbf L=m(\mathbf r\times \mathbf v)$$

Thus, while the ball was going in the circle of radius, its angular momentum was

$$L_{\rm initial}=mvR$$

where $R$ is the radius of the circular path. Just after you leave the string, the body continues going with the same velocity as before. It is easy to see that the value of the [cross product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) ($\mathbf r\times\mathbf v$) does not change, thus the angular momentum stays the same as before, i.e.

$$L_{\rm final}=mvR$$